# How to change image appearance before while loop in C# WinForms program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Form not running scripts before while (int<10) statement.

I'm trying to make a program that changes a pictureBox's image before jittering around the screen a bit. (joke/test program, new to coding)

for some reason, it doesn't change the appearance of the image until the end, instead of before the While loop.

heres the important parts of the code, the random value is a global value.

```
        private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imgPeter.Image = Properties.Resources.retep; //why does this not work?!
            touhou = 0;
            while (touhou < 10)
            {
                int x = rnd.Next(0, (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width - this.Size.Width));
                int y = rnd.Next(0, (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height - this.Size.Height));
                this.Location = new Point(x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                touhou += 1;
            }
            imgPeter.Image = Properties.Resources.peter;
        }
```

Does anyone know any fixes? anything i can try? I've tried adding it to the loop itself to no avail.

Comment: It will not rerender the picturebox until the function exits. You can try the simple Application.DoEvents() after each picture is assigned or you can create a randomizer function using the async await pattern to have it draw to the form during each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> //why does this not work?!

It does.  But the code continues to execute on that same thread, and later you then assign a new value to `imgPeter.Image`.  All of this is single-threaded blocking code, so basically the "last one wins" when the form is re-drawn.  Similar to:

```
x = 0;
x = 1;
x = 2;
```

At the end of this code, `x` will equal `2`.  It *did* equal `0` and `1`, very briefly, but nothing was ever done with it during those states.

In the context of Windows Forms, one old approach that is still commonly used (for better or for worse) is to force the form to re-draw:

```
imgPeter.Image = Properties.Resources.retep;
Application.DoEvents(); // <--- here
touhou = 0;
// etc...
```

Though honestly it's a bit of a hack.  And keep in mind that the use of `Thread.Sleep(10);` on the main UI thread could still result in unexpected UI "glitches".

You may want to consider making use of `async` and `await` instead, replacing `Thread.Sleep(10);` with something like `await Task.Delay(10);` (after making the overall method `async`).  The benefit of `async` operations is that the host application can continue with its normal operations (such as re-drawing the screen).

For example:

```
private async void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgPeter.Image = Properties.Resources.retep;
    touhou = 0;
    while (touhou < 10)
    {
        int x = rnd.Next(0, (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width - this.Size.Width));
        int y = rnd.Next(0, (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height - this.Size.Height));
        this.Location = new Point(x, y);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        touhou += 1;
    }
    imgPeter.Image = Properties.Resources.peter;
}
```

**Note for future readers:** The use of `async void` exists **only** to satisfy backward compatability with Windows Forms event handlers.  It should **never** be used outside of that very specific purpose.  Use `async Task` for otherwise `void` methods which need to be `async`.

Comment: Should note that the two assignments to `imgPeter.Image` are leaking 2 bitmaps per click